# Trying to identify strings that were segmented from one DB to another (using Excel), what's the best formula/else to use?

Tags: excel

A single string in Text DB1:

`TEXT_DIALOGUE1_STREET`

This string contains multiple lines and was automatically segmented in DB2:

```
TEXT_DIALOGUE1_STREET01
TEXT_DIALOGUE1_STREET02
TEXT_DIALOGUE1_STREET03
TEXT_DIALOGUE1_STREET04
```

I have to find out what strings in DB2 were also part of DB1.

On top of that, the DB is 700k strings strong.

What formula/VBA can I use to find all segmented strings that were part of DB1?

I tried multiple things and formulas (VBA macros found here, search, find, exact, etc...) but none of those help me as they don't find out that:

`TEXT_DIALOGUE1_STREET` is part of `TEXT_DIALOGUE1_STREET01`, to give me a 1 or a 0 in a third column, for example.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What about one input sample and one expected output sample?

Comment: 700K strings sounds like something more proficiently done with some dedicated text processing tool -- i.e., a VB or PowerShell script, not Excel. If you have to do this repetitively, fixing the source somehow (by injecting another process, for example) still sounds like a better idea than trying to get Excel to fix it.

Comment: So here it's only a one time thing and I feel like I'm very close to the solution using Excel. I am happy to do multiple batches of the file as it's a very unique event (new db and needs a workaround this one time).
Is there a formula I could use to find out what strings in t second db contain at least the ones in the first?

Like: =FIND(StringDB1+2characters,DB2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it is not entirely clear, exactly what you are trying to do.

However, it sounds like you have a list of strings from DB1, and a list of strings from DB2. Some or all of the strings in DB2 have come from DB1, some of which may have been split into multiple strings and have had two numerical digits appended.

My assumptions:

- Strings which have not been split have not been changed.
- Strings which have been split will always have had exactly 2 characters added.

If so, this formula should do what you need:

```
=IFNA(
    INDEX($A:$A,
        IFNA(
            MATCH($C2,$A:$A,0),
            MATCH(LEFT($C2,LEN($C2)-2),$A:$A,0)
        )
    ),
    "Not in DB1"
)
```

[image]

The way this works is to first check for an exact match of the DB2 string in the list of DB1 strings.

If one isn't found it then checks for an exact match of the DB2 string (minus the last two characters) in the list of DB1 strings.

If found, it returns the original DB1 string. If not it returns "Not in DB1".

You should be able to adjust for what you need.
If I have not understood the problem or my assumptions are incorrect, please let me know.

Comment: It worked!
I've been playing with the Match function and tried to implement the LEFT (2 CHAR) for hours now. It will help this huge month long project we have here. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. Excel's string functions aren't the easiest. For example, you cannot tell it what characters to remove, you have to tell it which ones to keep, which often requires the use of `LEN` within other functions. If it solved your problem, please accept my solution as the answer by clicking the tick to the left.